# less css for ubuntu (and compilation automatically)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-construction, less

I tried simpless, but is not supported now for linux. I tried with wine, and later another alternatives. I don't want to type: lessc file.less > file.less each time I modify a file.

Any good compiler, confortable, automatically,  for less CSS?

What is the linux tool that has same functionality as WinLESS i.e. that compiles less files whenever they change taking into account which less files include which?

Comment: For posterity, one of these might be suitable: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious way is to run the javascript implementation on Node.

For Ubuntu, start by installing `nodejs` and `npm`, then see e.g. [these instructions](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) for compiling LESS to CSS with Node. You should get it going with something like

```
npm install -g less
lessc mystyle.less
```

Comment: The supplied link isn't working anymore.  Any other ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Changed to a working link, though `lessc` is basically all you need to know.