# Less CSS compiler on Ubuntu: How to watch dependencies and compile on save

Tags: ubuntu, less

I just switched to Ubuntu (12.04)  from Windows and I'm struggling to get a solution to compile my .less files just the way I used to do by using  the "Winless" app.
This app's beauty is that I just have to monitor a folder, save the main file...  and everything that was changed in the dependent files get compiled as well.

I googled for an hour and have seen many answers but none of them is straightforward. And I'm a ubuntu noob, so things are difficult to understand. The closest one is [less css for ubuntu (and compilation automatically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862846/less-css-for-ubuntu-and-compilation-automatically), but it does not work as expected at all.

Can someone please point me to the right direction? I would like clear instructions about what I need to install and config in order to get a similar behavior of the "WinLess" program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your less files are stored in subfolders of `less/`, you can watch for changes with inotifywait:

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Then create a `autocompile.sh` file:

```
#! /bin/bash
while inotifywait -r less/*
do
  lessc less/main.less > css/main.css # your compile command
done
```

Don't forget to give it execution rights:

```
chmod u+x autocompile.sh
```

And run it:

```
./autocompile.sh
```

Your compile command will be run every time a file in `less/` will be modified.